# Django functional test: selenium 'live_server_url' doesn't load static files

Tags: django, selenium, django-testing, django-pipeline

I'm using `django-pipeline` for loading static files.

Strange thing is that `StaticLiveServerTestCase`'s `live_server_url` can not load static files correctly.

Here is part of code:

```
class ProductSetupTestCase(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super(ProductSetupTestCase, cls).setUpClass()
        # place category
        cls.place_category = PlaceCategory.objects.create(name="학교")

        # subject category
        cls.subject_category1 = SubjectCategory.objects.create(name="사람")
        cls.subject_category2 = SubjectCategory.objects.create(name="꽃병")

        for i in range(5):
            name = 'name' + str(i)
            product = Product.objects.create(
                name=name,
                place_category=cls.place_category,
            )

            product.subject_category_set.add(cls.subject_category1)
            product.subject_category_set.add(cls.subject_category2)

            product.variation_set.create(color='black')
            product.variation_set.create(color='single')
            product.variation_set.create(color='multi')


class CartItemEditTest(ProductSetupTestCase, StaticLiveServerTestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(2)
```

`Firefox` browser comes up and I execute follow command:

`self.browser.get(self.live_server_url)   # self.live_server_url value is localhost:8081`

And when I check `js` file using development tool, it shows like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/message.8d038600d898.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

When I copy the `src`(`http://localhost:8081/static/js/message.8d038600d898.js`) and paste it in new tab, it doesn't show `Not Found`.

Now I used other url, `http:localhost:8000`, which is `django runserver url`.

`self.browser.get(`http://localhost:8000`)

When I checking this time, it load static files pretty well:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/message.js" charset="utf-8"></script>`

Why does it happend? Should I not use `live_server_url` anymore?

Comment: I've not used django-pipeline, but just discovered selenium browsers also do caching (of course), could this be a case of that?

Comment: @Danimal No, I'm experiencing the same problem and, by setting a long Selenium wait timeout, I'm able to open the DOM inspector and poke around. It's trying to make the request, but it's getting a 404 error.